# Content of $block->getAdditionalHtml() in list page

Tags: magento2

In vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml, there is a code line `<?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>.` From where did get this data?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an additional html for a block with the `$block->setAdditionalHtml("<div>test</div>")` call.
For now, the core never uses this possibility.